# How to change keyboard shortcut for Compiz Magnifier (currently alt-enter)

Tags: unity, compiz, shortcut-keys

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity3D.

When I press `Alt+Enter` (a keyboard shortcut used by a number of things, especially Sublime Text), the Compiz magnifier is launched (creating a box around the cursor, and zooming the contents of the box).

I tried to change the keyboard shortcut in CompizConfig Settings Manager (the "Magnifier" effect).  I changed it to `Ctrl+Alt+Space`, which is working for me.  However, Alt+Enter *still* triggers the effect.

If I disable the effect, it stops.  So I know it is the magnifier effect.  I just can't figure out why `Alt+Enter` is still triggering the effect even after changing the shortcut.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bug and I am afraid it is currently in low priority. I guess the best would be to enable / disable per requirement.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/770515

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use magnifier, you could disable it entirely, as shown in [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-786327.html)

> Install "simple-ccsm" from Synaptic.
>   System -> Preferences -> Simple CompizConfig Configuration Manager
>   On the Accessibility tab, uncheck "Screen Zoom."

Comment: I was hoping to continue using it, but with a different keyboard shortcut.  The new keyboard shortcut works, but the old one seems to continue.  I'm wondering if it's hard-coded in somewhere... Thanks anyway :)